# Sidenotes with perpage renumbering

Tags: numbering, sidenotes

I'd like to use sidenotes with per page renumbering.

With footnotes, I always do this with `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}`, but that doesn't work with sidenotes. So I tried this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{perpage}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}
\MakePerPage{sidenote}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Hello}

    \blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}

    \chapter{Hi}

    \blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}

\end{document}
```

It doesn't work, however, because the renumbering is not really per page but somewhere halfway each time. Is there a way to make this work?

Not using per page is not an option, because the numbers get into the thousands at the end of the book.